# Http Post to a .NET Core 3.1 C# controller from Angular 8 component

Tags: c#, angular, http-post, asp.net-core-3.0

I am attempting to post a string from my angular component into my C# controller. I am able to call the method in my controller but the string passed in is always null.

Controller

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OracleCFOController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public OracleCFO Post( string Connection)
        {
            var result = new OracleCFO();
            result.ConnectionString = Connection;
            result = _OracleCFO.SelectedFOCustomer();
            return (result);
        }
    }
```

Component

```
export class FleetOutlookSynoviaComponent implements OnInit {

public CFO: OracleCFO[];
public selectedDB: any;

constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject("BASE_URL") baseUrl: string, public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.http = http;
 }

  Types: DbTypes[] = [
    { name: 'CFO' },
    { name: 'DFO' },
    { name: 'SFO' },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}

  onChange(instance: string) {

    console.log("Changed!" + instance + "");

      this.selectedDB = this.http.post('' + "oraclecfo", instance).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

I just need to pass in the DbType so I know which instance of my DB to connect to. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab) to get the **exact** payload being submitted to the server. Include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your C #.

For data recovery in "POST" you should have this:

```
public OracleCFO Post([FromBody] string Connection)
```

Hope to have helped you a little, see you soon!